# Code runs extremely slowly inside Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, performance

I'm doing some experiments with doing work (in this case, a MD5 brute-forcer) on Google App Engine using the MapReduce framework.

I'm having an issue where the code runs extremely slowly inside GAE, even just using the development server

This code https://github.com/jordan-thoms/Hash/blob/f982956f41313cd4fe3b5105aee21ea11bd3af16/src/nz/net/thoms/hash/mapreduce/HashMapper.java will only handle approximately 4,000 hashes per second (this is time inside a single call to map(), and there is no google app engine apis used at all inside it).

I took the code outside and ran it standalone - https://github.com/jordan-thoms/Hash/blob/f982956f41313cd4fe3b5105aee21ea11bd3af16/src/nz/net/thoms/hash/StandaloneTest.java , and that version will do over 1 million per second. It's the central loop that's running slower, which is strange since none of that code has anything to do with the google app engine.

I've tried running profilers on the Google App engine code, but I haven't found anything useful - seems to be a ton of calls to checkRestricted() and things like that though. I tried removing the security manager

Even this simple code:

```
        int i;
    for (i=0; i< 1000000; i++) {
        i += 2;
        i += (int) Math.sin(i * (i + (int) System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
    long enda = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("took " + (enda - starta) + " i:" + i);
```

Runs in 117 ms if I put it in a normal program, and in over 400ms inside a servlet in the developer mode, on the same processor.

(Interestingly, the mapper gets about 60,000 hashes done per second on the production Google App Engine. So a lot faster, but still very slow compared to a standalone program)

Comment: I don't really know, but before checking anything else what JIT (and relevant options) does GAE use, and what does your standalone code use? I ask not because I can usefully do anything with the answer, but because if you knew maybe that would help you :-) Also, part (probably not all) of that factor of 15 difference between production GAE and your standalone could just be that your machine is faster than the effective CPU speed they give to each app. As for the development server, raw speed there probably not a priority for Google!

Comment: Thanks - I used visualvm to look at the process for each, and I couldn't see any custom jit options for the GAE server and they are both using Hotspot 20.6-b01. Is there somewhere else I should look?

Comment: I meant the production GAE options -- you'd think they use good optimization, but for all I knew you were using better. I don't know if/where they document what they use, but if you aren't doing anything special then I wouldn't immediately expect them to be multiple times slower. I wouldn't try to puzzle out the development performance, like I said I doubt it's a priority, so if they've crammed the dev server code full of instrumentation there might be nothing you can do about that.

Comment: take System.currentTimeMillis() out of the loop, it may use a cache value updated by a different thread but also may lead to a system call depending on the the impl. The former is a likely optimization due to the habit of calling the function overly zealous by java programmers, yet it's always worth the effort to remove the unneeded operations out of a tight loop body. Security manager doesn't matter for the example provided.

Comment: on a side note: why map-reduce for an embarrassingly parallel algorithm. you just need the "map" part. Also the microbenchmark won't get the very good optimization, since it never exists the loop and the only way to optimize is via OSR (on-stack-replacement) that has sub-par results and also it factors in compilation time, i.e. you need warm-up. Also a GAE instance can be like 10-20 slower than a normal desktop/laptop.

Comment: WRT the System.getCurrentTimeMillis - that's not code I'm using, it was just some code I wrote to demonstrate how simple java code runs slower purely from being inside the GAE framework even on the same CPU. That's all true, but doesn't explain why it runs 4x faster if I take it out of the GAE servlet. I'm using the mapper simply as a easy way of distributing the work.

Answer (score 1):

The default [frontend instance](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings) has 128MB of memory and a 600MHz CPU limit. This could explain the performance difference.

Comment: I changed the instance type to the fastest one and the speed improved from c.60,000 per second to c.250,000 per second per instance. Still, I can get about 1.3 million using only one thread on my desktop. I'm currently working on getting this running on ec2 using hadoop, It'll be interesting to see how the performance compares.

Answer (score 0):

MapReduce iterate over every DataStore entity which is slow in comparison to a pure hadoop mapper. Consider iterating over a blob, or group your hashes in chunks. Keep in mind that a single map process can handle 10 minutes of works, then you can determine what will be the optimal size of each chunk of data to process.

Comment: I'm actually doing that - The issue was that the code inside the map function was running really slowly on google app engine, and even slower inside the development server. I've actually switched to using a hadoop cluster on amazon and it's working much, much better.

Answer (score 0):

According to my measurements with CPU-bound tasks, app engine is about ten times slower than one would expect given the specs of the instances. For example, a calculation that typically takes 3 seconds on my 2.5 GHz machine typically takes 30 seconds on a 2.4 GHz backend instance.

Regarding the local development mode, out-of-the-box performance of app engine is even worse. However, this can be mitigated to a certain extent by setting setting the vm argument -Dappengine.disableRestrictedCheck="true", in particular when using a custom class loader.